# Parallel stringify (serialize) to JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, asynchronous, parallel-processing

In my react-native app I need to stringify (serialize) big objects and not to block js thread - asynchronous api that uses another threads, something like this:

```
JSON.stringifyAsync({ foo: "bar" }).then(x => console.log(x));
```

Please don't suggest to wrap JSON.stringify into Promise, it just defers blocking of js thread.

Comment: So the first choice didn't work. What streaming JSON parser have you tested and what problems did you find there? Do you have any information on what you've already done?

Comment: I don't need streaming json parser, i need just true async one. If you have an answer pls just give it. And whats the reason of your downvote?

Comment: @ssube - How would a streaming parser help with OP's problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that streaming parser would help, because by its nature it's async, hence non-blocking, for example this one should do the job: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stream-stringify

Comment: @MaximMazurok if it is 100% JS then it can't be non-blocking.

Comment: @AlexanderDanilov I'm pretty sure they don't use any native modules and supposed to work in browsers, see my demo for this question: https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok/non-blocking-json-stringify-demo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible. It's an issue for node.js (see [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7543), [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2031), and [here](https://github.com/mohsen1/async-json/issues/6)) and I don't think the situation is any better for browsers or other JS engines.

There is an EcmaScript proposal (see [here](https://github.com/mohsen1/async-json)) to add functions `JSON.parseAsync` and `JSON.stringifyAsync` methods. I don't know the status of this proposal. From the proposal: *"There is no way of transpilating the actual effect of this proposal."* So it looks like the proposer(s) agree that there's currently no way to do this.

Comment: This is sooo bad.. Thanks for the answer. If i understood right it is impossible bcs nothing can leave node thread except a string.

Comment: @AlexanderDanilov - Yeah, it seems like a serious shortcoming. Sorry I couldn't offer up anything better.

Comment: I will be glad if you vote to reopen this question bcs you provided pretty good answer for one who seek it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can split the objects and merge the processed parts at the end.

Or do something like this:

```
async.eachOf(obj,function(value,key,callback){
  async.setImmediate(function(){

    // do something

  });
}, function(err,reply){

});
```

Comment: this is just a bad hack, i need true async

Comment: http://azimi.me/2015/07/30/non-blocking-async-json-parse.html?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email